# Concate values in the same column from different rows with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 0],
                        ['B', 1],
                        ['C', 1],  
                        ['D',2],
                        ['E', 3],
                        ['F', 3],
                        ['G',3]],columns=['Name','Idx'])

>>> df
  Name  Idx
0    A    0
1    B    1
2    C    1
3    D    2
4    E    3
5    F    3
6    G    3
```

I want to concate the "Name" values if they have the same "Idx".
In this case, it will become like this:

```
>>> df
    Name  Idx
0      A    0
1  B C D    1
2      D    2
3  E F G    3
```

How to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you have an extra `D` for index `1` in the expected result